# How to find broken links using the spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

is there a way to find broken links using the **spreadsheet**? I've already found some ready-to-use solutions, but they only checked the status code of the URL.
I need to find out if a link in cell C is in the source code of the URL in cell A. I also have information about anchor text. Right now it looks like this, and I don't have any way to check it other than manually: `http://prntscr.com/10ivj2y`
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

*Use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to create a function that makes a request to the desired url with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).*

### Step by step

- Open `Apps Script` clicking on `Tools > Script editor` and you will see the script editor. It is based on [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) and it allows you to create, access, and modify Google Sheets files with a service called [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).
- Write a function with the following features:

  - Input: the url to check
  - Trim the url to avoid errors with [.trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)
  - Make a request to the specific url with [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
  - Define some parameters to avoid problems when making the request

    - `'muteHttpExceptions': true` to avoid an error that breaks the function
    - `'followRedirects': false` to avoid 3xx responses redirect to another destination (200)
- Get the response code the `response` with [getResponseCode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode())
- Call the function from any cell in your Spreadsheet. For instance, if you have an url in `A2`: `=getStatusCode(A1)`

### Code

```
function getStatusCode(url){
   var options = {
     'muteHttpExceptions': true,
     'followRedirects': false
   };
   var url_trimmed = url.trim();
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_trimmed, options);
   return response.getResponseCode();
}
```

### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [UrlFetchApp: fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [HTTPResponse: getResponseCode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getResponseCode())

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reaction. Using this solution Ill only get the status code of the URL, but I need to find out if the URL in cell C is in the source code on the URL in cell A. Is it possible to do that? Thanks

Comment: Could you explain how you do the check manually? Could you give an example? The only thing I can think of is to use the [getContentAsText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontenttext) method to see the HTML content of the initial url